# Call a function in main function in the global part in python 3.4

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
import math
def nthroot(x,n):
    c=math.pow(x,1/n)
    return(c)

a=float(input("enter the value of x"))
b=float(input("enter the value of n"))
d=nthroot(c)
print (c)
```

the error is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):`
  File "C:/Users/Soham Pal/Desktop/dec_to_octal.py", line 8, in <module>
    d=nthroot(c)
NameError: name 'c' is not defined
```

Comment: So, what _is_ that variable `c`? Where is it defined?

Comment: `nthroot` takes two arguements and **returns** a `c` (the name is not important)

Comment: @ForceBru sir...actually am new to python...can you help me in order to run the above code

Comment: That line should be `c = nthroot(a, b)`

Comment: Please read the errors [and understand what they are trying to tell you](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/). You called a function using some `c` variable. We would like to know where you think you have  defined that because it is not within some "global part"

Comment: @PatrickHaugh oh yeah...executed...thanks a lot

Answer (score 2):

The problem is [variable scope](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scope_(computer_science)). `c` does not exist outside of the function

You might want to try giving the correct parameters to the function, though since if you did have a `c` variable, you would get a different error.

```
import math
def nthroot(x,n):
    return math.pow(x,1/n)

a=float(input("enter the value of x"))
b=float(input("enter the value of n"))

d=nthroot(a, b)  # See here
print(d)
```

It might also help if you assign the value of the "x" input to an actual variable named `x` so that you understand what its purpose is for

Answer (score 1):

Since you have created a function which takes two parameters , you should pass 2 arguments when calling it . Your code should look like -

```
import math

def nthroot(x,n):
    c=math.pow(x,1/n)
    return(c)
a=float(input("enter the value of x"))
b=float(input("enter the value of n"))
d=nthroot(a,b)
print (d)
```

Now , we are passing two values that we have taken from the user to the function (a and b here).
The function is calculating result , storing the result in c , and returning c . We are storing this result in d . And finally we are printing d.